# How to check if tag contains a specific string?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have something like this in xml:

```
<doc>
  <people>
    <adress>
      <town>nameoftown</town>
    </adress>
  </people>
</doc>
```

I want to check if tag town contains specific string. I know I can use count function but I want to do it in this way:

XSL:

```
<ABC>   
   <xsl:variable name="counter" select="0"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="/doc/people/adress/town">
        <xsl:if test="contains(text(), 'nameoftown')">
     <xsl:variable name="counter" select="$counter+1"/>  
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each> 
 <xsl:value-of select="$counter"/>
</ABC>
```

Comment: So you need to count `town`s which contains `nameoftown`?

Comment: yes (10 more characters)

Comment: Why don't you want to use `count` function?

Comment: Variables don't work that way in XSLT. They are immutable

Answer (score 2):

**XSLT is a *functional language*.**

Among other things this means that a variable, once defined (and initialized) cannot be modified.

The immutability of variables doesn't mean that any problem, which can be solved in an imperative way/language by modifying variables, cannot be solved using a functional language.

**To turn to the specific problem**: what you want to do in a very complicated way (in 7 lines) can be expressed as a simple one-liner:

```
count(/*/*/*/town[contains(.,'nameoftown')])
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT, an empty node set evaluates to false, so you can simply do this:

```
<xsl:if test="/doc/people/adress/town[.='nameoftown']">
  Found at least one example of nameoftown
</xsl:if>
```